# Adding 1474257977 bad clusters to bad cluster file

Tags: chkdsk, runtime

my chkdsk is at the point where it is now adding 1474257977 bad cluster to bad cluster file. mu question is how long should i expect this to take. it is a 10tb hdd with roughly 6tb free. it has been on this screen for a little over 20 hours. I assume it will take uo to a few days. just wanted to make sure it's not stuck/hung or anything. dont want to risk ruining a brand new hard drive. (power outtage caused the bad sectors to my knowledge)

Comment: Do you have a backup of all the data on it?

Comment: No I do not at this point

Comment: Too bad. Sadly, if you need to keep that data I don't have an answer for you.

Comment: worse case cenario i can recopy the data from another one of our computers, i just don't have a copy of the data here

Comment: Add that last comment to your question, please.

Comment: chkdsk /R is a 5 stage process.  Stage 4 checks the data, Stage 5 checks the free space.  Which stage are you on?

Answer (score 0):

1 474 257 977 bad clusters is a lot.

Let's start from the end:

> dont want to risk ruining a brand new hard drive.

I'm sorry to say that, but you should prepare to consider this drive ruined. Maybe it isn't, but my professional guess is that it probably is.

> power outtage caused the bad sectors to my knowledge

Well it shouldn't. Not on that scale.

### Safest course of action

For me, it would be:

1. Check if you *really* can recopy the data from another one of your computers. If you don't, skip the rest of this list.
2. Stop chkdsk
3. Use [S.M.A.R.T.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) to see if there is any permanent damage. And check HDD mileage, some of my friends bought new ones from reputable vendors and yet they got used ones in new boxes.
4. If damage was permanent, ask for warranty fix or replacement. Power outage shouldn't have such effects. If your drive is older than it is supposed to be, demand your money back!
5. If S.M.A.R.T. reports HDD to be OK, make a clean format and recopy. Probably faster than waiting for chkdsk.

If not all of your data is available outside of this HDD, waiting is your only option and you have no choice but to wait. [This answer](https://serverfault.com/a/55900/190745) seems to estimate chkdsk speed at about 6GB/h, but from my experience it is not linear, more massive failure and speed drops faster. In your case few days wouldn't surprise me and if some data was terribly important I'd wait like a week — but I admit I didn't have a HDD failure this big in years, so it is hard to estimate.

Last but not least, if chkdsk finish successfully, still use S.M.A.R.T. to see if your disk was new and if it is still healthy enough to use.